# "Promise to tell" in negative

Tags: meaning

Is there any subtle nuance in meaning between:

- > You promised not to tell anyone.
- > You promised to tell no one.

Comment: By far the biggest difference, as indicated by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promised+not+to+tell+anyone%2Cpromised+to+tell+no+one&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromised%20not%20to%20tell%20anyone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpromised%20to%20tell%20no%20one%3B%2Cc0), is that your second alternative is pretty "dated". I'm not aware of any regional variation here, or subtle *semantic* differences.

Comment: Another variant is *You promised to not tell anyone*, which is slightly emphatic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Both the sentences are grammatical, with the same meaning.

The use of "not .... anyone", though a bit less formal than "no one", is far more common and idiomatic. Besides, no one is stronger and more definite than not.... anyone.

Comment: So **no one** is formal and strong while **anyone** is less formal and not that strong?

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/no-one-nobody-nothing-nowhere

Answer (score 5):

Both of you sentences are correct, although

> You promised **not to tell** anyone

may be preferable since it emphasizes the **not telling**

Comment: Or the latter may be preferable in that it emphasizes no one, not even your wife, say, or the priest to whom you confessed your sins in strictest confidence, or your psychiatrist.

Comment: @userr2684291 's suggestion of "you promised to not tell anyone" might be the best of both worlds... at least to me, it emphasizes the whole **not tell anyone**

Comment: I remember in Red Cross babysitter school (yes, that's a thing...or was many moons ago) we were told to say "Walk!" instead of "Don't run!" because little kids tend to hear just the verb, without the negation; I suspect the version of this for adults is that many English speakers will notice negation in front of the verb more easily than negation following the verb.

Answer (score 2):

They are essentially the same, but you asked about any subtle nuance.

To me, **promise not to tell** is less definitive than **promise to not tell** or **promise to tell no one**. "Promise not to tell" is bigger picture. Of all the things you do, telling won't be one of them. "Sorry, I promised not to tell but with everything I do, I forgot about that one."

It could even be taken as wiggle room. "Sure I promised not to 'tell', I only hinted."

**Promise to not** is a specific and unequivocal promise about the action in question.